# How to choose correct value of inductor in a circuit

Tags: inductor, heat

I have a PCB where SIM900 is used. As [SIM900](http://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/SIM900_HD_V1.05.pdf) needs at least `2amps` of current during transmission burst so I have used [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) for its power. Below is its schematic:

[image]

In the circuit, I am using `200uH inductor`. During a call, SIM900 stops suddenly and inductor is blown. This happens for the first time so I replaced it and again I tried and the same thing happened. Inductor starts heating up and then it get blown. What value of inductor should I use with this circuit.?

Comment: What's with all those little plus signs in the schematic?  It looks like just a lazy screen shot from Eagle.  If you don't care about your project, there's no reason anyone else should care about it either.  Also, you can't expect everyone to know what a SIM900 or LM2567 is off the top of their heads.

Comment: Please provide a description (what kind of chip/function?) and reference links (datasheet ideally) for SIM900 and LM2576. As Olin said, we don't necessarily know what they are.

Comment: Also, is your inductor rated for the peak current through it? (Not necessarily equal to the average/DC current which I infer is 2A.)

Comment: Yeah we need the datasheet for the inductor, as well as the 2576 and the SIM900.

Comment: @OlinLathrop When we give names to the net in eagle, it comes with the little plus sign.

Comment: I have added links to the datasheet. I purchased the inductor from a local market so dont really know its part number or datasheet

Comment: The plus signs are more than that.  They are the origin anchors for each item, not just for net names.  The point is those are for you.  We shouldn't have to see any of them, and they don't belong on a schematic you show to other people.  Don't be so lazy and just dump a screen shot on us.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I have updated the image with the screenshot taken from the pdf of the schematic.

Comment: That's better, although exporting the image would have probably been easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the inductor is not rated for the current.  You want 2 A average out, so the inductor must be rated for more than that.  Purchasing a component from a local market without a datasheet is no way to source parts.

The LM2567 is a rather old part requiring high inductance.  I've only looked at the first page of the datasheet, but it says right up front that it only runs at 52 kHz fixed frequency.  That requires a large inductor.

You need to actually **read the datasheet**.  Right on page 1 it shows a Schottky diode.  Your 1N4004 is totally inappropriate here.  It's long reverse recovery time is probably significantly stressing the LM2576.  That may actually be the real cause of the failure.  The inductor appears to be the problem after the LM2567 output fails shorted to the input.

Especially when you don't really understand how something works, you need to **follow the directions** carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You should assess if you really need a continuous 2A from your power supply.

GSM modules may take a peak current of up to 2A when they transmit, but the transmission only lasts 577us, and it only transmits every 4.615ms. That gives an average current of 2A/8, or 250mA. Also, the 2A figure is a worse case. You will only see 2A when you are in an area of poor GSM signal strength, and using a poor or badly matched antenna.

Usually a power supply rated for a continuous 500mA is adequate, but you need to ensure that the voltage on VBAT doesn't droop during the transmission. According to the datasheet you are allowed a 0.3V droop, so using a 1000uF low ESR capacitor connected to VBAT close to the GSM module should hold up VBAT during the transmission. I often use 2x or 3x 470uF low ESR tantalum capacitors here.